# Separate computation from socket work in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, concurrency

I'm serializing column data and then sending it over a socket connection.
Something like:

```
import array, struct, socket

## Socket setup
s = socket.create_connection((ip, addr))

## Data container setup
ordered_col_list = ('col1', 'col2')
columns = dict.fromkeys(ordered_col_list)

for i in range(num_of_chunks):
    ## Binarize data
    columns['col1'] = array.array('i', range(10000))
    columns['col2'] = array.array('f', [float(num) for num in range(10000)])
    .
    .
    .

    ## Send away
    chunk = b''.join(columns[col_name] for col_name in ordered_col_list]
    s.sendall(chunk)
    s.recv(1000)      #get confirmation
```

I wish to separate the computation from the sending, put them on separate threads or processes, so I can keep doing computations while data is sent away.

I've put the binarizing part as a generator function, then sent the generator to a separate thread, which then yielded binary chunks via a queue.

I collected the data from the main thread and sent it away. Something like:

```
import array, struct, socket
from time import sleep
try:
    import  thread
    from Queue import Queue
except:
    import _thread as thread
    from queue import Queue


## Socket and queue setup
s = socket.create_connection((ip, addr))
chunk_queue = Queue()


def binarize(num_of_chunks):
    ''' Generator function that yields chunks of binary data. In reality it wouldn't be the same data'''

    ordered_col_list = ('col1', 'col2')
    columns = dict.fromkeys(ordered_col_list)

    for i in range(num_of_chunks):
        columns['col1'] = array.array('i', range(10000)).tostring()
        columns['col2'] = array.array('f', [float(num) for num in range(10000)]).tostring()
        .
        .

        yield b''.join((columns[col_name] for col_name in ordered_col_list))


def chunk_yielder(queue):
    ''' Generate binary chunks and put them on a queue. To be used from a thread '''

    while True:   
        try:
            data_gen = queue.get_nowait()
        except:
            sleep(0.1)
            continue
        else:    
            for chunk in data_gen:
                queue.put(chunk)


## Setup thread and data generator
thread.start_new_thread(chunk_yielder, (chunk_queue,))
num_of_chunks = 100
data_gen = binarize(num_of_chunks)
queue.put(data_gen)


## Get data back and send away
while True:
   try:
        binary_chunk = queue.get_nowait()
    except:
        sleep(0.1)
        continue
    else:    
        socket.sendall(binary_chunk)
        socket.recv(1000) #Get confirmation
```

However, I did not see and performance imporovement - it did not work faster.

I don't understand threads/processes too well, and my question is whether it is possible (at all and in Python) to gain from this type of separation, and what would be a good way to go about it, either with threads or processess (or any other way - async etc).

**EDIT**:

As far as I've come to understand -

1. Multirpocessing requires serializing any sent data, so I'm double-sending every computed data.
2. Sending via `socket.send()` should release the GIL

Therefore I think (please correct me if I am mistaken) that a threading solution is the right way. However I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

I know cython can release the GIL off of threads, but since one of them is just socket.send/recv, my understanding is that it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The first thing to do would be to measure how fast your current implementation sends data (in megabytes per second or etc) and compare that with how fast your computer's network card is capable of sending data to the same destination (which you can test e.g. by doing an FTP transfer or similar).  If you're already at or near your network bandwidth limit, then there will be little or nothing to be gained by making your code more efficient, as your code is not the bottleneck.

Comment: I in fact wish the network speed to be the bottleneck - to have data ready in parallel so that the total time, if possible, is "slightly more" than the netowrk time itself.. Currently I test on my own comp (127.0.0.1) and time is 50-40 for binarizing-sending

Comment: That's a good goal, but keep in mind that the TCP stack itself already runs in parallel to your code -- that is, each TCP socket has an outgoing-data buffer (which you can configure using the SO_SNDBUF TCP option), usually located in kernel space, which the TCP stack drains as fast it can shovel data across the network.  Therefore data transmission happens even while your other code is executing; as long as your code is producing data fast enough that the buffer rarely or never becomes empty, then you'll be getting the benefit you want anyway.

Comment: Therefore parallelizing/pipelining your program will help only if your program is unable to keep the buffer from emptying otherwise -- but a much easier approach in that case might be just to set the buffer's maximum size to be larger, and produce more data at once.

Comment: Do you mean that socket.sendall() is actually instantaneous due to the buffer? In my case I do need to wait for the recv() as well before I can send the next chunk, as the confirmation is delivered once the chunk has been loaded to the database. I just don't know how to make data crunching and sockets parallelize well in Python

Comment: sendall() will be instantaneous only if the amount of data you passed to it fits entirely into the socket's outgoing-data-buffer.  Otherwise it will block until the buffer has drained enough that it can fit all of the supplied data into the buffer.  (Unless you have the socket in non-blocking mode, of course, in which case I think it will throw an exception if it can't fit all of the data into the buffer).

Comment: Note that (waiting after each send for a confirmation to be received from the remote peer) will drastically lower your throughput, since then your throughput will be strictly limited by the aggregate round-trip time of the network(s) between your program and the other program.  If your goal is to maximize network throughput, you'll want to 'pipeline' the transfer of data as much as possible.

Comment: I can't control the other half of the round-trip, my goal so have as little overhead over it, so I wish to keep generating data while waiting for response

Comment: Processes can not increase performance with a single socket. You've opened multiple transactions locally, but you have a connection on the network side. You cannot stream with a TCP connection (you may have typed the protocol),
You need to check the responses to all the processes that are opened (you must wait for the package to be terminated to check the success). The codes you typed are far from what you want. Your question should be: **How do I set up multiple connections to a single server?**

Answer (score 3):

You have two options for running things in parallel in Python, either use the `multiprocessing` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)) library  , or write the parallel code in `cython` and release the GIL. The latter is significantly more work and less applicable generally speaking.

Python threads are limited by the Global Interpreter Lock ([GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)), I won't go into detail here as you will find more than enough information online on it. In short, the GIL, as the name suggests, is a global lock within the CPython interpreter that ensures multiple threads do not modify objects, that are within the confines of said interpreter, simultaneously. This is why, for instance, `cython` programs can run code in parallel because they can exist *outside* the GIL.

---

As to your code, one problem is that you're running both the number crunching (`binarize`) and the `socket.send` inside the GIL, this will run them strictly serially. The `queue` is also connected very strangely, and there is a `NameError` but let's leave those aside.

With the caveats already pointed out by Jeremy Friesner in mind, I suggest you re-structure the code in the following manner: you have two processes (not threads) one for binarising the data and the other for sending data. In addition to those, there is also the parent process that started both children, and a queue connecting child 1 to child 2.

- Subprocess-1 does number crunching and produces crunched data into a queue
- Subprocess-2 consumes data from a queue and does `socket.send`

in code the setup would look something like

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

work_queue = Queue()
p1 = Process(target=binarize, args=(100, work_queue))
p2 = Process(target=send_data, args=(ip, port, work_queue))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

`binarize` can remain as it is in your code, with the exception that instead of a `yield` at the end, you add elements into the queue

```
def binarize(num_of_chunks, q):
    ''' Generator function that yields chunks of binary data. In reality it wouldn't be the same data'''

    ordered_col_list = ('col1', 'col2')
    columns = dict.fromkeys(ordered_col_list)
    for i in range(num_of_chunks):
        columns['col1'] = array.array('i', range(10000)).tostring()
        columns['col2'] = array.array('f', [float(num) for num in range(10000)]).tostring()
        data = b''.join((columns[col_name] for col_name in ordered_col_list))
        q.put(data)
```

`send_data` should just be the `while` loop from the bottom of your code, with the connection open/close functionality

```
def send_data(ip, addr, q):
     s = socket.create_connection((ip, addr))
     while True:
         try:
             binary_chunk = q.get(False)
         except:
             sleep(0.1)
             continue
         else:    
             socket.sendall(binary_chunk)
             socket.recv(1000) # Get confirmation
    # maybe remember to close the socket before killing the process
```

Now you have two (three actually if you count the parent) processes that are processing data independently. You can force the two processes to synchronise their operations by setting the `max_size` of the queue to a single element. The operation of these two separate processes is also easy to monitor from the process manager on your computer `top` (Linux), `Activity Monitor` (OsX), don't remember what it's called under Windows.

---

Finally, Python 3 comes with the option of using co-routines which are neither processes nor threads, but something else entirely. Co-routines are pretty cool from a CS point of view, but a bit of a head scratcher at first. There is plenty of resources to learn from though, like [this](https://medium.com/@ianjuma/python-co-routines-with-async-await-29032664e03c) post on Medium and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) talk by David Beazley.

---

Even more generally, you might want to look into the producer/consumer pattern, if you are not already familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for the multiprocessing example.  I understand that socket ops release the GIL, so I shouldn't need mp for this. Do you perhaps have any insight on this?  If you can give a simple threading example and a %timeit comparison for completenesss, I'd be happy to give you the bounty

Comment: Blocking sockets release the GIL when you're doing IO, that's not your problem. The problem is the queues connecting the threads together, those are inside the GIL and thus synchronise the threads depending a little bit on what kind of data your sending over the socket. The larger the packet to longer the blocking IO call will take, and the longer the other thread(s) can run. I'll leave the timing exercise to you, you can use the mp code by just replacing `Process` with `Thread`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but not sure I understand - Once the binarizer is done with queue.put(), can it not get back to work? If not, how can this be circumvented with threads?

Comment: no because everything the binariser works with touches the GIL, and the only thing that doesn't touch the GIL is `socket.send`, so as long as the other thread is doing anything other than `socket.send` the binariser can not move until it has acquired the GIL which in turn stops the other thread (except if the other thread is in `socket.send`). The amount of parallelism you get from threads is dependent on the program being IO or CPU bound, CPU bound programs do not benefit from Python threading.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use concurrency to improve performance in CPython I would strongly recommend using multiprocessing library instead of multithreading. It is because of GIL ([Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)), which can have a huge impact on execution speed (in some cases, it may cause your code to run slower than single threaded version). Also, if you would like to learn more about this topic, I recommend reading [this presentation by David Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf). Multiprocessing bypasses this problem by spawning a new Python interpreter instance for each process, thus allowing you to take full advantage of multi core architecture.

Comment: Thanks, but I suspect the GIL is not an issue here